# Swift: Determine if array contains array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Im trying to figure out how to check if array contains another array:

```
var grid: [[Int]]!
grid = []
grid.append([1,1])

if grid.contains([1,1]) {

}
```

but the line

> if grid.contains([1,1]) {

throws the error:

> Contextual type '@noescape ([Int]) throws -> Bool' cannot be used with
>   array literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift arrays doesn't conform to Equatable by default. But you can still compare them in the predicate:

```
if (grid.contains { $0 == [1,1] } == true) {

}
```